# WSO2 DSS: tryit doesn't work

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have installed WSO2 DSS (4.0.5) as a feature of BAM 2.2.0 and created a data service which works perfectly when I call it externally (e.g. from Java or PHP).
However when I use "tryit" tool it shows an error:

```
<soapenv:Reason xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">
       The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/OTRS_DS?tryit 
       and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, 
       please contact the server administrator.
   </soapenv:Text>
</soapenv:Reason>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you don't have tryit features installed. You have to install try-it features similar way you did when installing dss features.